# Can't create a form for comments in a post RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a comment box/form under my article in rails, but it keeps raising an error saying unknown attribute: post_id

My form code

```
<%= form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :commenter %> <br>
<%= f.text_field :commenter %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :body %> <br>
<%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

For my comment create action

```
def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
redirect_to post_path(@post)

respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

It raises an error for

```
<%= form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

saying unknown attribute: post_id

Thanks all!

Updated Error : undefined method `posts'

```
<tr>
       <td><%= comment.commenter %></td>
       <td><%= comment.body %></td>
       <td><%= comment.posts %></td>
       <td><%= link_to 'Show', comment %></td>
       <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path(comment) %></td>
       <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you don't have a `post_id` column in `comments` table which is causing the error.

Looking at your code, I am guessing that you want a 1-M relationship between `Post` and `Comment` model.

Make sure the relationship is setup correctly in the models as below:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  ## ...
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  ## ...
end
```

After this, you must make a `post_id` column in `comments` table as a reference to `posts` table. This should resolve your `unknown attribute: post_id` error.

You can create `post_id` column in `comments` table by generating a migration:

```
rails generate migration AddPostRefToComments post:references
```

After this run `rake db:migrate`

**UPDATE**

> *I'm getting undefined method `post_comments_path'*

In order to fix the above issue, you should have nested routes in `routes.rb`

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

**UPDATE 2**

Change

```
<td><%= comment.posts %></td>
```

To

```
<td><%= comment.post %></td>
```

Note singular `post` and not plural `posts`.

Comment: You can use `AddPostIdToComments` also BUT its better to use `Ref` as we are creating a Post reference. This will add a `post_id` with an index on it.

Comment: Restart the rails server.

Comment: Same problem, what I did was rails generate migration AddPostIdToComments post_id:integer and that cleared the first error but now I'm getting undefined method `post_comments_path'

Comment: I keep toying around and it still doesn't work. I think it has to do with my associations, is this correct?
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments
end
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end

Comment: What error are you getting now? What all changes you made in the code? Update the question with latest changes.

Comment: Its a different issue. Your original issue is resolved now. Please see UPDATE 2 in my answer

Comment: Got it, will figure out the rest by myself. Thanks a lot! One last question, when you scaffold something does it automatically generate an id? For example if I scaffold Store does it automatically generate a store_id or do I need to put it as apart of the scaffold? Thanks!!

Comment: If you generate a scaffold for `Store` then a primary key named `id` (and not `store_id`) would be automatically generated and you don't need to pass it to scaffold command.